# How can I copy artifacts with all dependencies from one maven repository into another?

Tags: maven, dependencies, copy, repository, artifacts

Here is my use case:  I am building a project that can only read from Repository A.  I have permission to add any artifacts I want into this repository, but I don't have administrative rights to manage Repository A.  Unfortunately, this repository currently lacks *most* of the artifacts I need.

Copying artifacts with dependencies from repo1.maven.org into this Repository A using maven deploy:deploy-file is time consuming.  Is there a tool that handles this problem for me?

I could even build a hybrid project (maven project with both repositories) for purposes of copying.  But I am restricted to using Repository A for the production projects automated build and run.

Comment: What `type` of a repository is `Repository A` - a simple http server or a repository manager like nexus?  If latter, you should be able to populate `Repository A` automagically through simple configuration.

Comment: As I said, I don't have administrative access to Repository A.  All I have is deploy:deploy-file

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in such way, that I would first create new repository for the project, filled with all artifacts needed to build it, and then I would write the script that would generate maven *deploy* command for each file inside, that not exists in Repository A.